# for loop: a string passes from "0" to "9"

Tags: c++, string, for-loop

I want to write a for loop that passes the strings for 0 till 9:

```
for (string j = "0"; j < "10"; j++) {

}
```

but it doesn't know the operator ++ (it gets an integer (1) and not a string "1").

I think to write: `j+="1"`, but then `j` will be `"01"` and then `"011"`...

**p.s. I don't want to use functions of `#include <string>` or something else. (stoi, etc)**

any help appreciated!

Comment: What exactly *can* you use?

Comment: Couls you please be more precise about your intention?

Comment: I have a size_baskets that can be between 0 to 20 (it a string). I have a function that get a string and print all the boalls in the basket number `i`. so I have to do something like: for(int i = 0; i < stoi(size_basket); i++) basket->print(i); but `i` have to be string, and I want use the stoi function (because it belongs to <string>, so I have to send a string.

Comment: and I can use <iostream>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that way, but...

```
char x[]={'0',0};
for(; x[0] <= '9'; ++x[0])
{
}
```

Edit: 0..99 version

```
char x[]={'0','0',0};
int stroffs = 1;
for(; x[0] <= '9'; ++x[0])
{
   for(x[1] = '0'; x[1] <= '9'; ++x[1])
   {
     char * real_str = x + stroffs;
   }
   stroffs = 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you!
how can I change it to work the numbers between 0 to 20?

Answer (score 2):

Loop with integers, then manually convert it to a string?

Like

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    string j(1, '0' + i);  // Only works for single digit numbers
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do your iterations with integers, and convert them to strings inside the loop, like this:

```
// Your loop counter is of type int
for (int i = 0 ; i != 10 ; i++) {
    // Use string stream to convert it to string
    ostringstream oss;
    oss << i;
    // si is a string representation of i
    string si = oss.str();
    cout << si << endl;
}
```

This works for any kind of integers without limitations.

[Here is a short demo](http://ideone.com/5IFoxy).

Answer (score 1):

You can do like `j[0]++` to increase first char to next ascii value. but this is only for '0'-'9'

**edit:**   Just an idea, not a perfect code: for `0` to `20`;

```
   i = 0;
   (j > "9") && (i==0) ? j[i]++ : (++i, j="10");
```

Comment: thank you.. is there a way to do it for the numbers between 0-20?

Comment: @AlonShmiel yes by conditionally you can use `+=` when value change from `9` to `10`

Answer (score 0):

With your constraints (although I have no idea how you use `string` without `#include <string>`):

```
const char* x[] = 
{
    "0", "1", .... , "10"
}

for ( int i = 0 ; i <= 10 ; i++ )
{
    x[i]....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use atoi with:

```
#include <stdlib.h> // or #include <cstdlib>

for (int j = atd::atoi("0"); j < std::atoi("10"); j++) {

}
```